# Communication among microservices: Apache Kafka vs Hazelcast's Topic

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, messaging, hazelcast

Disclaimer.
I have experience with [Hazelcast](https://hazelcast.com/) and [Vert.x](http://vertx.io/). I'm new to [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/). Sorry if my question look preconceived, it's not.

There are two widespread ways to arrange communication among microservices: REST and messaging. In my region, when someone says they're using messaging for communication among microservices - it de facto means Apache Kafka.

I am interested to know why Apache Kafka is better fit for communication needs among microservices than Hazelcast's Topic? Is it better? Because of which guarantees, features or architecture decisions?

The Hazelcast's example for cluster wide messaging looks as following:

```
// node #1
Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance()
         .getTopic("topic")
         .publish(new Date());

// node #2
Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance()
         .getTopic("topic");
         .addMessageListener(message -> /*Do something here*/);
```

Also there is Vert.x (very roughtly speaking actors framework) written on top of Hazelcast's topics and member discovery.

*Is Kafka messaging better for communication among microservices?*

Answer (score 12):

This is a bit generic question, and I'm not a Kafka expert; but I will try to tell about Hazelcast's messaging features.

Hazelcast contains two types of topics; one is regular `ITopic` and the other one is Reliable Topic, which again implements `ITopic` interface. The usages are mostly the same, but they differ in what they guarantee. Regular `ITopic` is based on Hazelcast's eventing mechanism, and does not guarantee message delivery. Reliable Topic is backed up by the `Ringbuffer`, and the events are not lost since the Ringbuffer is configured with one synchronous backup by default. Also, each Reliable `ITopic` gets its own Ringbuffer; if a topic has a very fast producer, it will not lead to problems at topics that run at a slower pace. Lastly, since the event system behind a regular `ITopic` is shared with other data structures, e.g., collection listeners, you can run into isolation problems. This does not happen with the Reliable `ITopic`. But with all these disadvantages, regular `ITopic` can run a bit faster since it uses fire&forget eventing mechanism.

Apache Kafka has its own great advantages; such as it is all built as a message streaming platform with a temporal persistent log, and therefore  has ability to store data to disk for fault-tolerance.

In summary, if you need message persistence with all features needed for messaging on your application, go with Kafka since it is more specialized. But if you need a in-memory data platform including support for messaging, go with Hazelcast.

Answer (score 0):

The messaging model/communication of Kafka is distinctly different from other mainstream messaging infrastructure as available. While most of the messaging infra make a clear distinction between a topic and a queue, Kafka strictly does not. ***Its topic can behave as a topic as well as a queue***, this flexibility is not available in Hazelcast.

Now. from the perspective of microservice design, this could make a huge lot of difference, in terms of the design options. Any microservice that leverages messaging is essentially an apparent synchronous communication over an asynchronous channel, as an example [NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/faq/what-is-nginx-how-different-is-it-from-e-g-apache/) model.

From that perspective take the below use case (example only):

1. There are 5 tomcats horizontally deployed with 2 web applications which are essentially subsystems of a larger system
2. Each of them have requirement to exchange data (read only on request) without having any other dependency (data exchange protocol is defined externally)
3. All interactions between the subsystems need to be optionally logged

The solution itself is simple, send request, wait for response till timeout, if response is received return or else return with exception.

From design perspective, it is quite a bit complicated though. Assuming an 'at most once' style of processing, the general design would be publish request to a queue, read response back from a topic. In Hazelcast it would require an IQueue (considering scaling is not a factor) and a ITopic.  In Kafka, it can be done with one topic, two partitions and consumer group ids. In addition, logging can be enabled or disabled by adding or removing additional consumers to the topic/partiions.

The above is merely an illustration of an example of how asynchronous communication can be achieved, both Hazelcast and Kafka (and for that matter JMS/Camel etc.) have their own set of flexibilities. Choice of a specific infrastructure would therefore, in large part depend on your communication design.